# List child pages within page template

Tags: pages, templates, id

I am building a page template within a theme that lists child pages for a product page.

Is it possible to change this so that it lists the children of the page the user is on rather than having to specify a page ID?

My code

```
<?php
$args=array(
  'post_parent' => 27641, // This page!
  'post_type' => 'page',
);
$my_query = null;
$my_query = new WP_Query($args);
if( $my_query->have_posts() ) {?>
    <ul>
  <?php while ($my_query->have_posts()) : $my_query->the_post(); ?>
            <li>
                <a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" title="<?php the_title_attribute(); ?>" itemprop="url">
                    <?php the_title_attribute(); ?>
                </a>
            </li>
   <?php endwhile; } ?>
   </ul>
<?php wp_reset_query();  // Restore global post data stomped by the_post().?>
```

Comment: You should be able to access the `global $post` object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ID of the current page is available via the global $post variable, so to get the ID use:

```
global $post;
$currentPage = $post->ID;
```

Then you can use $currentPage in your query :)

Comment: No probs, glad to help.